# Spring side fork grease

Tags: suspension, grease

First post here and also first time servicing my forks, which are 2006 Marzocchi Dirt Jam Pro.

I was wondering if anyone knows what kind of grease i should be using for the spring in the left leg. The manual I have been going off just says "smear the left spring with the recommended grease" but doesn't actually detail the recommended grease.

What is the recommended grease?

---

[image: Manual image]

Comment: Can you link the portion of the manual you're dealing with?

Comment: This is the manual I have been going off. http://my-sport.spb.ru/manual_1/2006-dirt-jam-pro.pdf PAGE 25

Comment: I edited in an image of section the page from the manual the OP is referring to.

Answer (score 4):

The grease on a coil spring is purely to reduce friction between the spring and the fork leg/stanchion. The choice of grease is non-critical beyond ensuring that it is compatible with the existing grease (or you clean the fork thoroughly to remove the old grease) and that it will not damage the seals. Natural rubber seals can be damaged by petroleum based greases however most fork manufacturers appear happy to use petroleum based calcium greases such as [Buzzy's Slick Honey](http://buzzysusa.com/) so this does not appear to be of much concern in practice.

The [2006 Marchozzi product manual](https://www.marzocchi.com/System/18499/2006-taiwan-uk.pdf) does not mention or recommend a specific grease type. The closest thing I could find to a recommendation was a [2012 video of a Marchozzi employee rebuilding a fork with a similar design](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/Tech-Tuesday-Change-the-Seals-and-Fluid-of-Your-Marzocchi-44-For.html) where around 17:40 he uses an amber coloured grease (likely calcium grease) to lubricate the dust seals. While there was no clear shot of the product used and no specific grease type mentioned, the recommendation was to use "lightweight low-friction grease".

Following that recommendation you would be safe using most types of general-purpose grease including castor oil based greases (as they will not degrade rubber seals), silicone or teflon grease (also safe to use with rubber), lithium grease, graphite grease, or calcium grease. Greases designed for high temperature/high pressure situations (such as automotive bearing grease) will not be as effective at lubricating a fork spring under typical use so should be avoided unless that is all that is available.

Comment: Welcome to SE - great answer.  I look forward to your future contributions.

Answer (score -1):

The "recommended grease" ?  I have no idea.

But since the area in question isn't made with fine tolerances, I'd say any automotive grease would be okay.  The purpose of the grease will be to prevent exposed steel surfaces from rusting or binding.

Personally I'd use marine grade grease for wheel bearings.  Its a bit tackier than regular grease but resists washing out a little better.

Comment: @MikeD Its not a recommendation - its a last resort in lieu of the right information.  Downvoter is right - this is a poor answer.

Comment: Ahh I see.. Ok i'll keep searching then.